# Remembering the URL a user was trying to access when redirected to Login page in Next.Js

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redirect, next.js, next-router

What I'm trying to do: If a user tried to go to the URL some-basepath/events/632dbb3f6852f but was not authenticated, I want to be redirected to something like some-basepath/login?redirect=events%2F632dbb3f6852f & after signing in, I should be taken to the URL I was trying to access.

(Note that here I encoded slashes as %2F but anything else that makes sense would also work)

What I tried in my `useAuth` custom hook which handles authentication:

```
if(user-not-logged-in){
   const asPath = router.asPath();
   console.log("as path = ",asPath);

   const encodedAsPath = encodeURIComponent(asPath);
   console.log("encoded as path = ",encodedAsPath);

   router.push({
      pathname:"/login",
      query: {redirect: encodedAsPath}
   });
}
```

and then in the login page:

```
useEffect(
   () => {
      const {redirect} = router.query;
      console.log("decoded redirect in login page = ",decodeURIComponent(redirect))
   },[router.isReady,router.asPath]
);
```

But when I navigate to the unauthorized page & I get redirected to login page I get the following results:
[image]

And the url of the page is:
[image]

And I can't understand what I did wrong.

Comment: The code you shared doesn't seem related to the 401 error you get. Where are you making the request to `/api/events/632dbb3f6852f`? Can you show us that code?

Comment: @juliomalves i ended up solving the problem by using ```window.location.pathname``` instead of using the next.js router

Answer (score -1):

I'd like to clarify 2 things.

1 - `/api/*` are server-handled requests. There might be a logic there which correctly gives a 401 response status code for unauthenticated users.

2 - as `/api/*` are handled in the server, you cannot run React-related features there.

If those statements above resonate with your code, I assume those 401 responses are correct and they aren't errors. That's only the way the browser shows it to you in the DevTools.

If those statements above do not resonate with your code. Please, clarify where you are implementing the code you've provided.